# how to hide div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to hide div if label which div contains set to 0.

here is my design:

```
<div id="pnltickethistory" class="thumb">
    <img alt="" src="../images/emblem-library_64.png" name="ibtninquiryhistory" width="64" height="64" />
    <br/>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbut_inquiry_histrory" runat="server" onclick="lbut_inquiry_histrory_Click">Enquiry History</asp:LinkButton>
    <div class="noti_bubble" id="noti_bubble1">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_inquiry_count" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**-----------------------------------------Updated---------------------------------------------**

and this is my java script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                 
     var g1 = $('#lbl_inquiry_count').val();
     if(g1=='0')
     {
     $('#noti_bubble1').hide();
     }
     var g2 = $('#lbl_query_count').val();
     if(g2=='0')
     {
        $('#noti_bubble2').hide();
     }
     var g3 = $('#lbl_post_count').val();
     if(g2=='0')
     {
        $('#noti_bubble3').hide();
     }
});
</script>
```

this is my css:

```
.thumb 
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:110px;
height:90px;
    padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-radius:25px;
-moz-border-radius:25px;
-webkit-border-radius:25px;
background-color:none;
border:#67849C solid 2px;
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;

}
.thumb:hover
{
width:110px;
height:90px;
background-color:#E7EBF3;
border:#67849C solid 2px;
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.thumb img
{
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:100;
}
.thumb:hover img
{
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    opacity:0.7;
}
.noti_bubble {
    position:absolute;
    top: -6px;
    right:-6px;
    padding:1px 5px 1px 5px;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10pt;
    border-radius:30px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px gray;
}
```

Comment: Please use *meaningful variable names* and leave it up to the tools to minimise them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got solution just add runat="server" to div which want to hide and you can simply use this div from code behind and make Visible = false;

Answer (score 2):

### *how to hide div using jquery*

Assuming `noti_bubble3` is class name of `div` to hide,

Simply,

```
$('.noti_bubble3').css('display', 'none'); // hide elements with class .noti_bubble3
```

or,

```
$('.noti_bubble3').toggle();
```

or

```
$('.noti_bubble3').hide();
```

For reference:

```
.css( property ) // will return property value
.css( property, value ) // will set property value
```

---

### Edit as per comment,

```
$('#noti_bubble3').css('display', 'none'); // hide element with ID noti_bubble3
```

or,

```
$('#noti_bubble3').hide();
```

or,

```
$('#noti_bubble3').toggle();
```

## Reference [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: i use this technique here i just want to hide div with it's id.Is above jquery is correct to take value from label ?

Comment: @shal if `noti_bubble3` is your `ID` just change selector and use `$('#noti_bubble3').hide();` to hide

Comment: @shal whaat is `$('#<%=lbl_query_count.ClientID%>')`?.This is invalid selector

Comment: @shal  `$('#label_id')` --> selects label with ID `'label_id'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46007/discussion-between-shal-and-pilot)

Comment: ya i follow ur steps and i update my script but i no changes occurs is  that problem with css so i put my css code.

Comment: ok i found solution just add runat="server" to div and set Visible=false from code behind. thank u..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.css('none')`, do `.css("display","none")`.

Then read up on [jQuery .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

use could use `$('...').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

To hide something using jquery, you can use the built-in hide method :

```
$('your_selector').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) or [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods. For example:

```
$('#my_div').hide();
```

or

```
$('#my_div').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

```
$("[id^= 'noti_bubble']").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that Label is set to 0 when it has text content '0'. Then you may use this code:

```
$('.noti_bubble').each(function() {
     var el = $(this).find('Label');
     if (!el.length) return true;
     var v = el.text();
     if (v == '0') $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: here how to find label simple it's 'id' or 'id.ClientID'

Comment: selection by class is more flexible than by id

Comment: ya but i want to hide div which inner label have 0 value. here i have three divs with class noti_bubble and i have to check every label that contain 0 value then hide it with div id.